# Configuring Django to use SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, django, sqlalchemy, configure

How can I configure Django with SQLAlchemy?

Answer (score -1):

There are many benefits of using SQLAlchemy instead of Django ORM, but consider **developing** a built-in-Django choice of SQLAlchemy
(to have something called `a production ready`)

By the way, Django ORM is going better - in Django 1.11 they added `UNION` support (a SQL basic operator), so maybe some day there will be no need to change ORM.