# django and sqlalchemy

Tags: python, django, orm, sqlalchemy

I'm fairly new to Django and have a basic question: I want to use an ORM that I can work with it for Django and other python projects,  so the basic question is Django ORM agnostic and if so how can I use SQLAlchemy with it for example?

If it's not, then what do you suggest for the above problem (using ORM objects that works with both Django and outside it)?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Option 1: Use the Django ORM for other projects.  [Using only the DB part of Django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/579511/using-only-the-db-part-of-django)

This works well.  I prefer it.

Option 2: Use SQLAlchemy with Django. [SQLAlchemy and django, is it production ready?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1154331/sqlalchemy-and-django-is-it-production-ready) and [Configuring Django to use SQLAlchemy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1011476/configuring-django-to-use-sqlalchemy)

This works well, also.  I don't prefer it because I don't like reconfiguring Django.